# select an image to show with dialog

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I select an image to show using dialog? I only can show an image when I know it's exact path. But I want to be like that dialog when you upload your photo to social networks or something. Now I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

img = Image.open(r"images\photo1.jpg")

show_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

panel = Label(root, image=show_img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the Tkinter FileDialog, let the user choose the image and use that location as string for your image http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm